# Index error after upgrade to EE 1.14.2.0: table catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer doesn't exist

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, error, indexing, ee-1.14.2.0

After I've upgraded my Magento to EE 1.14.2.0 the cron `enterprise_refresh_index` always gets this error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer' doesn't exist' in /var/www/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

I don't get why this table doesn't exist. Shouldn't Magento create it in the process of the refresh index?

Comment: If you've got EE I believe you'll get support?

Comment: Yes, I could try it that way.

Comment: @Richard which shows you never used EE support.

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly Hi Tim, no, I've never used EE either though

Answer (score 5):

There's a Magento patch SUPEE-5984, which addresses these kind of Enterprise Refresh Index problems.

Comment: I could not find this patch, if you have a copy it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please contact Magento support at support@magento.com. Thank you.

Comment: You can find the patch at https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/blob/master/EE1.14/PATCH_SUPEE-5984_EE_1.14.2.0_v1.sh.

Answer (score 5):

We encountered this error after a database restart in production and after a first reindex on a local development environment, running EE 1.14.2.3.

What worked for us was the following:

1. Disable the flat product catalog
2. Observe that the indexer runs successfully
3. Enable the flat product catalog
4. Observe that the indexer runs successfully

Comment: I tested this workaround and it appeared to work for me, allowing the enterprise_refresh_index job to complete successfully

Comment: Works for me too.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference:
The error doesn't occur when I revert the file `app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Product/Flat/Refresh.php` to our previous version 1.14.0.1.
The new parameter `$resetFlag` in the function `_reindex` seems to cause the problem.

Comment: "Awesome", just ran into the same issue. Will try if that solves also our problem.

Comment: I can confirm that reverting the file solves the error. Did an update from 1.14.0.1 to 1.14.2.0 and just created a patch file with the modified content of Refresh.php. Next: contacting EE support.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl did they provide you any update on this?

Comment: @Sergei Guk: So far I did only reset the file and did not ask for official support or patch. An Update to 1.14.2.1 (maybe solved there?) is in the queue. Need to investigate further when there is time to.

Comment: An update to 1.14.2.1 does not fix this. The Magento support has a patch for it but I still have to test it.

Comment: The patch worked for me running 1.14.2.0 and .1 - SUPEE 5984

Comment: I seem to have this exact same problem after upgrade from 1.14.0.1 to 1.14.2.1. Have requested the patch from Magento support as well as advice on optimal setup when running the indexer via scheduled events

Comment: Looks like SUPEE 5984 patch worked, however ran into another problem where the indexer would throw a fatal error "Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted". Backtraced the issue down to a Enterprise_Mview query which was returning 25 million records in an array and as a result, ran out of memory.  I think its because the above issue has been an issue for so long that the version_id never updated and the changelog just built up each day due to the fatal error. What we did to resolve this now was truncate the table then let the cron / indexer run its natural course. The indexer is now running

Comment: I just had a look for SUPEE 5984 (I have Enterprise login) but I could not find that patch. Where is it?

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment yet on the existing comments/answers, but I can confirm that SUPEE-5984 appears to resolve the issue, at least for our client who encountered this issue (they have over a million products, so it still hasn't finished running, but it IS running now... ). We opened a ticket with Magento through our client's support contract with them and Magento got us the patch in less than an hour.

Comment: Caution, if you updated to 1.14.2.3 after patching, you have to apply the patch again because it is **not included in the latest release**

Comment: For the record, in 1.14.3 the issue seems to be fixed in a different way and the patch is not needed anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Magento EE 1.14.2.3, but the above solutions didn't work for me. I found out the problem was in `Enterprise_Catalog_Helper_Product::getFlatColumns`. I solved it by changing the line

`if ($columns !== null) {`

to

`if ($columns !== null && $columns !== false) {`

Of course: don't edit the core file directly, but do a rewrite.