# Category url rewrites corrupted

Tags: category, url-rewrite, indexing

I'm getting corrupted urls in enterprise_url_rewrite that look like this:

```
category/subcategory.html-274
```

Note, the number is after the suffix. When I reindex the url_redirect process, the number increments to 275.

Any body have any idea?

Comment: Which modules are you using that interfere with rewrites?

Comment: I don't know. This just started happening this morning after working for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the enterprise_refresh_index cron. I applied patch 5984 and this fixed it. See [Index error after upgrade to EE 1.14.2.0: table catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer doesn't exist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76915/index-error-after-upgrade-to-ee-1-14-2-0-table-catalog-product-entity-tmp-index)